# Converting code in other languages to Mathematica code

Tags: interoperability

Do you know of any work being done on the idea of bringing in code from other languages like Perl, PHP, Python, etc.? That is, import the code in some way and then convert it to *Mathematica* code?

Comment: You can load java classes and execute those "within" mathematica using JLink, they actually run in a linked JVM.  The same would apply for python code via JYthon.  Similarly .Net classes may be run using NetLink and IronPython would also work.

Comment: I found the question to be confusing, so I rephrased it.  Please verify.

Comment: No, Mathematica has no built-in ability to do this.  I am not aware of any packages either, though there might be some limited ones.  What you *can* do is call code written in other languages from Mathematica.  I am aware of interfaces to C/C++, Java (and other JVM-based languages), .NET, R, MATLAB, Clojure, NetLogo, Python (limited).  There are probably others.

Comment: With some probability, I see myself making some code designed to convert a subset of SymbolicC to MMA code, but never finishing it. But who (else) cares about SymbolicC :P?

Comment: @Szabolcs The question is stated that your comment could be an answer, please consider posting it.

Comment: @Kuba OK, done.

Comment: f2mma does this for simple FORTRAN programs, but I could only find references to f2mma, not the software itself (and your question doesn't mention FORTRAN, so this might be even more unhelpful).

Answer (score 2):

No, Mathematica has no built-in ability to do this. I am not aware of any packages either, though there might be some limited ones.

What you *can* do is call code written in other languages from Mathematica. I am aware of interfaces to C/C++, Java (and other JVM-based languages), .NET (see all three [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/MathLinkAPI.html)), [R](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/RLink/guide/RLink.html), [MATLAB](http://matlink.org), [Clojure](http://clojuratica.weebly.com/), [NetLogo](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/mathematica.html), [Python (limited)](https://code.google.com/p/pythonika/). There are probably several others.